# how to list and choose an old version of R

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

How can I change my version from R 4.1.2 to version 4.0.0 or older?

I'm having trouble installing some packages, as they are unavailable in the current version.

I know there is a command that shows multiple versions of r in the terminal and that you can choose from, but I'm not remembering it

OS: ubuntu 22.04

Comment: MacOS had a switcher program. Not sure about Ubuntu. Searching produced: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216307/switch-between-different-versions-of-a-program-r

Comment: you could try finding the package source and building them yourself https://github.com/cran if the packages are no longer available for newer versions of r, there is probably good reason

Answer (score 1):

Inside the OS this is *very* difficult as it cuts against the grain of the OS which always wants to serve you

```
max          package_version
subject to   distribution_release
```

so you just cannot get the, say, Ubuntu 18.04 packages inside of Ubuntu 22.04.

But do not despair: Docker is *the* solution for this.  Here is an example (markdown snippet) I show to my students:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:latest R --version | head -1
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.0.3 R --version | head -1
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.6.3 R --version | head -1 
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29) -- "Holding the Windsock"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.5.3 R --version | head -1 
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"
$ docker run --rm -ti r-base:3.4.2 R --version | head -1
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
$
```

(That was from last fall so no R 4.2.0 yet, and done on Ubuntu 21.04 at the time.)

And this works -- the example is not made up. Install `docker` (which I am running on Ubuntu via the `apt` repo by the Docker folks) and pull in the containers you want.

Comment: Hello. I'm relatively new to linux and I don't think I got it right.
I did a "sudo apt-get install docker" and followed the commands, for example "docker run --rm -ti r-base:4.0.3 R --version | head -1", but the result was
"Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install docker # version 20.10.14, or
sudo apt install docker.io # version 20.10.12-0ubuntu4
sudo apt install podman-docker # version 3.4.4+ds1-1ubuntu1
See 'snap info docker' for additional versions."

Comment: Yes, sorry, Linux can be overwhelming.  Just file this under "it can be done" and when you have a calm moment start reading up on Docker tutorials, maybe with a bend towards Ubuntu.  It is not complicated technology and very worthwhile.  But the is once again a small learning step.